# Products in catalog_product_flat_1

Tags: magento-1.8, product, flat-catalog

Is it normal that not all our products are not listed in catalog_product_flat_1 even after I have reindexed  catalog_category_product or did i reindex the wrong index here ?
I want to avoid reindexing all the indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catalog_category_product` is the indexer for category / product relations. The indexer for the flat catalog table is `catalog_product_flat`. Note that products with the status "Disabled" are not indexed.